# Emitter changes its colour to default yellow

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

I am trying to create some explosion using the emitters. I am adding my custom texture which is red and also I set colour ramp to red. But the problem is that if in scene I add it, it changes its colour to the yellow. What causes this?

This is how I add it:

```
func explode(spreiteNode: SKSpriteNode, explosionNode: SKSpriteNode){
        let explosion = SKEmitterNode(fileNamed: "Explosion")
        explosion?.position = spreiteNode.position
        explosion?.physicsBody?.isDynamic
        explosion?.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = true
        self.addChild(explosion!)


        self.run(SKAction.playSoundFileNamed("dead", waitForCompletion: false))

        spreiteNode.removeFromParent()

        self.run(SKAction.wait(forDuration: 2)) { 

            self.restartGame()
        }

    }
```

And those are my emit properties:

[image]

And in the preview they are actually red:

[image]

Comment: Probably because of the particle blend mode. Change Add to Alpha. As per docs, Add mode blends the source and destination colors by adding them up, which probably not what you want.

Comment: @Whirlwind That was it. Thank you very much. I think you should add it as a answer, maybe someone finds it useful too.